# How to split columns from a single column in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

```
df<-data.frame(Col=c("1::F::1::10::48067","2::M::56::16::70072","3::M::25::15::55117"))


df%>%separate(df,c("Sr No.","Gender","Occupation","Age",,"Zip-code"),"::")
```

Error Message:

> ```
> Error in if (!after) c(values, x) else if (after >= lengx) c(x, values) else c(x[1L:after],  : 
>   argument is of length zero
> ```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: something like this 
before <- data.frame(
  attr = c(1, 30 ,4 ,6 ), 
  type = c('foo_and_bar', 'foo_and_bar_2')
)

before %>%
  separate(type, c("foo", "bar"), "_and_")

Comment: Did you meant `before %>% separate(type, c("foo", "bar"), sep="_and_")` which works for me

Comment: have a look at the image uploaded..This works for me too,I am trying to do it on an actual dataset and it is throwing an error.Have a look at the screenshot of the first 10 rows of that dataset(link in the question),The columns are" Sr No.","Gender","Age","Occupation","Zip-code" appearing in one column separated by ::

Comment: @mihirdeshpande then please provide an example data that would throw the same error.

Comment: @zx8754 have a look at the edit

Comment: The correct syntax for `separate()` includes both the data frame and column to be separated, so `df%>%separate(.,Col,c("Sr No.","Gender","Age","Occupation","Zip-code"),"::")` works correctly.